# Accessing Extra-Date using social_auth for django

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am using social_auth in my django application to use facebook connect. I have followed steps which are given in the documentation (https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth). But I am struggling in accessing extra info such as 'user_about_me','profile_pic' etc. I am able to see the access token in my db column but I am really struggling in making use of it.

Can someone help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a Profile model for your user in order to store additional data if thats what you need. With the token you should be able to make use of the Graph Api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
django-social-auth is just that.. auth, not a facebook app.

Comment: Yes I agree with you on this point but I was struggling in accessing that extra info using that access tocken. So If you could help me with that, it would be helpful for me.
bingo_user.hometown=request.user.social_auth.values_list('extra_data', flat=True)

could you help me by modifying this line, if possible

Comment: data = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/me?   access_token='+access_token) 
data = data.read()
j_data = json.loads(data)
j_data['birthday']'